# Issue Finding Assemblies when Running PS Scripts with System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell

I am working on a C# application that uses the PowerShell class in System.Management.Automation to run PowerShell scripts remotely. In one PS1 file I have made I am using som assemblies

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
```

This works fine when running the script directly in PowerShell on a computer, but when running it through the application I get this error.

```
Error running instruction: Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\System.Windows.Forms.dll' because it does not exist.
```

I am not sure why it is looking for the assembly dll files in that directory when running the PS file through the application.

How can I find where it find the correct dll files when executing the script locally in PowerShell?

**Edit:** Might the problem be that PowerShell instance invoked by the application is not using the Global Assembly Cache, and if not how can I make it use it?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell/SMA and .NET is your application targeting, and how do you invoke the script (this would probably be easier if you posted the code your having issues with)? :-)

Comment: Its a huge f*** code and I don't have the full overview unfortunately, but we are using SMA version 7.0.0. I believe the problem is that it is that it is not using the same directory to search for assemblies as when running PowerShell directly on the computer (which I believe is looking in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL"). I do not know how to tell the PowerShell instance we are invoking through the application to use the same directory.

Comment: If all the scripts are written for Windows PowerShell and depend on _.NET Framework_ assemblies, you're gonna have to use S.M.A. version 5.1 - 7.0.0 runs on .NET Core.